# Increment Variable count in for-each in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

I want to Increment variable in for-each loop. Here is my code.

```
<xsl:variable name="i" select="1" />
<xsl:variable name="oddEven" select="1" />
<xsl:for-each select="//ProfileBR">
    <xsl:variable name="j" select="$i + 1" />
    sharad j :: <xsl:value-of select="$j"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:variable name="iBR" select="substring(//BRValue,$i,1)" />
    <xsl:variable name="jBR" select="substring(//BRValue,$j,1)" />
    <xsl:if test="$iBR='1' or $jBR='1'">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$oddEven='1'">
                <tr class="sbListOddCell">
                    <xsl:call-template name="JobInfoSection">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ii" select="$i"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="jj" select="$j"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="iiBR" select="$iBR"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="jjBR" select="$jBR"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </tr>
                <xsl:variable name="oddEven" select="0" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <tr class="sbListEvenCell">
                    <xsl:call-template name="JobInfoSection">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ii" select="$i"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="jj" select="$j"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="iiBR" select="$iBR"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="jjBR" select="$jBR"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </tr>
                <xsl:variable name="oddEven" select="1" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="$j + 1" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to increment i and j in every iteration but it ends up with 3 and 2 respectively after each iteration.

How can I increment i and j.

Thanks,
Sharad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use position() to get the count of the iteration inside the for-each like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="j" select="$i + position()" />
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but its not working as I want because every time the `i` will set to 1 and so every time the `i` will be just 1 ahead of the position.
My general logic is.
`i=0;
j=0;
for(10 rows)
{
    j=i+1;
    i=j+1;
}`

Comment: I hope you edited the line which is just under the xsl:for-each.. and there won't be any need of the last `xsl:variable` instruction at the end of `xsl:for-each`

Comment: Hi, my requirement was to update both `j` as well as `i`, but thanks for giving the hint of using `position()` it helped and solved my issue. I used this `<xsl:variable name="i" select="((position() - 1) * 2) + 1" />` and for j it will be `i+1`. My second concern is if you see the oddEven logic, this is also of same type i.e the value doesn't persist. I want to display `<tr>` with two styles i.e. `sbListOddCell` and `sbListEvenCell` one after another. Can you guide me how can I achieve that.

Comment: This question is quite different than the question was meant for.. if the answer helped you please accept it by ticking it and ask a new question for this..