# Display alternate style class in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to display alternate style class in XSLT.
Here is my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="oddEven" select="1" />
<xsl:for-each select="//ProfileBR">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="((position() - 1) * 2) + 1" />
    <xsl:variable name="iBR" select="substring(//BRValue,$i,1)" />
    <xsl:variable name="jBR" select="substring(//BRValue,$i+1,1)" />
    <xsl:if test="$iBR='1' or $jBR='1'">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$oddEven='1'">
                <tr class="sbListOddCell">
                    <xsl:if test="$iBR=0">
                        <td></td>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:call-template name="JobInfoSection">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ii" select="$i"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="jj" select="$i+1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="iiBR" select="$iBR"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="jjBR" select="$jBR"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:if test="$jBR=0">
                        <td></td>
                    </xsl:if>
                </tr>
                <xsl:variable name="oddEven" select="0" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <tr class="sbListEvenCell">
                    <xsl:if test="$iBR=0">
                        <td></td>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:call-template name="JobInfoSection">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ii" select="$i"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="jj" select="$i+1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="iiBR" select="$iBR"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="jjBR" select="$jBR"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:if test="$jBR=0">
                        <td></td>
                    </xsl:if>
                </tr>
                <xsl:variable name="oddEven" select="1" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Currently the oddEven logic is not working as the value does not persist.

Note: The position is not at all related with the display. If the condition satisfy than only display the `<tr>` else not.

Comment: XSLT variables are immutable. I believe you have been shown another approach in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147255/increment-variable-count-in-for-each-in-xslt-1-0).

Comment: The previous question was for different Issue which is solved. So this is the latest code by updating the fixes.
I am banging my head to find that ANOTHER APPROACH. :(

Comment: I suggest you post a minimal, but complete example of your XML input and the expected output. Posting (only) a (partial) code that doesn't work is not very likely to move this forward.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the CSS will be better for this case or may be Javascript ..

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td{
}
```

I think you can also use a counter if you have changed the loop style to be a recursive like this

```
<xsl:template name="loop">
        <xsl:param name="other param"/>
        <xsl:param name="count"/>
        <!-- logic then recurse and pass the counter with $counter + 1-->
</xsl:template>
```

As you can each time path the param with a new value.

I hope this could help!